# NoSuchElementException - junit test error

Tags: java, html, selenium, junit

I am using selenium junit testing.
If i try with selenium ide, the test goes well, but with junit it gives me this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#firstName"}
```

I think that the span doesn't redirect to the page it should (but in normal schedule it does).

```
@Test
  public void adminCreateDoc() {
    driver.get("http://localhost:8080/login");
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(550, 706));
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Accesso amministratori")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("8245");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("prova1");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("btn_createDoc")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("firstName")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("firstName")).sendKeys("Marco");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lastName")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("lastName")).sendKeys("Battiato");
    driver.findElement(By.id("doc_type")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("doc_type")).sendKeys("Cardiologo");
    driver.findElement(By.id("id")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("id")).sendKeys("855555");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("prova1");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".glyphicon-send")).click();
  }
```

I've tried with xpath, but without success...

HTML page with span redirection:

```
<body>
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div align="center">
            <h2>Gestione dottori</h2>
            <table  class="table table-striped table-responsive-md">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Specialit&agrave</th>
                </tr>
                <tr th:each="doc: ${listDoc}">
                    <td th:text="${doc.getId()}"></td>
                    <td>Dr. <span th:text="${doc.getFirstName()}"></span> <span th:text="${doc.getLastName()}"></span></td>
                    <td th:text="${doc.getDoc_type()}"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <a th:href = "@{/admin_createdoc}"><span id="btn_createDoc" class="plus bg-dark" >+</span></a>
            <hr>
            <div class="col col-lg-2 align-self-center">
                <div class="p-1">
                    <form th:action="@{/admin_logout}" method=post>
                        <button name="btn_logout_profile" id="btn_logout_profile"
                            type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log Out</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Which redirect to this page:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-start">
            <form th:action="@{/admin_homepage}" method=get>
                <button name="btn_back_profile" id="btn_back_profile" type="submit"
                    class="btn btn-info">
                    <span class="fas fa-chevron-left"></span>
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div style='text-align: center'>
            <form class="well form-horizontal" action="#"
                th:action="@{/saveDoctor}" th:object="${doc}" method="POST"
                id="contact_form">
                <fieldset>
                    <!-- Form Name -->
                    <legend>
                        <center>
                            <h2>
                                <b>Doctor Creation Form</b>
                            </h2>
                        </center>
                    </legend>
                    <br>

                    <!-- Text input-->

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span> <input name="first_name"
                                    th:field="*{firstName}" placeholder="Doc First Name"
                                    class="form-control" type="text" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Text input-->

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Last Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span> <input name="last_name"
                                    th:field="*{lastName}" placeholder="Doc Last Name"
                                    class="form-control" type="text" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Type</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span> <input name="doc_type"
                                    th:field="*{doc_type}" placeholder="Doc Type"
                                    class="form-control" type="text" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Text input-->

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Id</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span> <input name="id"
                                    th:field="*{id}" placeholder="Doc ID" class="form-control"
                                    type="number" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Text input-->

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span> <input
                                    th:field="*{password}" name="doc_password"
                                    placeholder="Doc Password" class="form-control" type="password"
                                    required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Button -->
                    <div class="form-group" align="center">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <br>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">
                                SUBMIT <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <div>
                <form th:action="@{/admin_logout}" method=post>
                    <button name="btn_logout_profile" id="btn_logout_profile"
                        type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log Out</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It looks like the error occurs on `driver.findElement(By.id("firstName")).click();` -- there is no element with ID `firstName`. Your `span#btn_createDoc` is being found just fine. Perhaps you are saying the click isn't bringing up the `firstName` element as you expect?

Comment: I thought it was a redirection problem because, trying to set a WebDriverWait before find element firstName, it doesn't go to the page it should, but I'm new to junit selenium so I'm not sure if it is the problem.

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what your whole page looks like. Can you share as much of the HTML as possible?

Comment: The fact that the error is happening after you click what appears to be a button `btn_createDoc` tells me that you need to add some waits around you find element commands.  It is probably going from one page/screen to another and the find_element command is not waiting for the DOM to load fully before it executes.

Comment: I've modified my post with more html code if it helps

Comment: explicit waits are your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failure is happening on this line

```
driver.findElement(By.id("firstName")).click();
```

ID as a CSS selector is `#firstName`. Since this is right after a page transition, my guess is that the page isn't fully loaded before the next line of code is run. This can sometimes happen on a modern site where the page is loaded but there's still stuff being loaded asynchronously in the background. The fix is to add a wait, specifically a `WebDriverWait`, to the following line. That is one option...

Instead of adding a wait piecemeal when it's found that you need it, I prefer to write helper methods that take care of common actions like `click()`, `sendKeys()`, etc. and then let those methods take care of the specific waits for me.

```
public void click(By locator) {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator)).click();
}

public void sendKeys(By locator, String text) {
    findElement(locator).sendKeys(text);
}

public WebElement findElement(By locator) {
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
}
```

Then you can change your script to

```
@Test
public void adminCreateDoc() {
    driver.get("http://localhost:8080/login");
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(550, 706));
    click(By.linkText("Accesso amministratori"));
    sendKeys(By.id("username"), "8245");
    sendKeys(By.id("password"), "prova1");
    click(By.cssSelector(".btn"));
    click(By.id("btn_createDoc"));
    sendKeys(By.id("firstName"), "Marco");
    sendKeys(By.id("lastName"), "Battiato");
    sendKeys(By.id("doc_type"), "Cardiologo");
    sendKeys(By.id("id"), "855555");
    sendKeys(By.id("password"), "prova1");
    click(By.cssSelector(".glyphicon-send"));
}
```

which I think makes it more readable, adds waits to everything in case it's needed with no extra code, and so on...

The next level is using the Page Object Model to contain the locators and methods for each page. Then your code gets cleaned up significantly, makes it near-human readable, and MUCH easier to manage.